# PHPExcel dynamically incrementing rows and columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am currently using PHPExcel to output an order's information to Excel.

I have the following foreach-statements that ultimate generate my data such as the city in which the order was made in, the restaurant name, etc.

Pardon the nested foreach-loops - it was the only way I could nest through all that many cities and legal entities and restaurants to generate the data the customer wanted.

Using an answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585231/1913389) which dynamically generates the row and column integer, I tried it in my code.

```
$row = 1; // 1-based index
$col = 0;

foreach ($this->data['total_by_city'] as $city_id => $total_city){
    $city_name = '';
    foreach ($this->data['total_by_legal_entities'] as $legal_entity_id => $total_legal_entity) {
        $legal_entity_name = '';


        foreach ($this->data['restaurant_by_legal_entities'][$legal_entity_id] as $restaurant_id) {
            $orders = $this->data['order_by_restaurants'][$restaurant_id];
            $restaurant_name = '';
            if ($orders)
            {
                foreach ($orders as $order_id => $order)
                {
                        $restaurant_name = $order['restaurant_name'];
                        $legal_entity_name = $order['legal_entity'];
                        $city_name = $order['city'];
                        echo $row . ", ". $col . "<br>";
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['city']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['legal_entity']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['restaurant_name']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['payment_method']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['order_number']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['date_created']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['customer_name']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['order_type']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['amount']);
                        $row++;
                        echo $row . ", ". $col . "<br>";
                        $col = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran my code, and attempted to open the .xlsx file, I received a "corrupted Excel spreadsheet" error in Excel.

To make sure that my rows and column (respectively) indices are correct, I printed them out:

```
1, 0
2, 8
2, 0
3, 8
3, 0
4, 8
4, 0
5, 8
5, 0
6, 8
6, 0
7, 8
7, 0
8, 8
8, 0
9, 8
9, 0
10, 8
10, 0
11, 8
11, 0
12, 8
12, 0
13, 8
13, 0
14, 8
14, 0
15, 8
15, 0
16, 8
```

From that observation, I see that the rows and columns indices I am using are incorrect. They are both in the wrong location and reset/incremented incorrectly.

My question is - how do I increment and reset my column and row indices correctly?

Comment: ... or take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37972341/4719732 to convert index values to column letters.
I don't know which way is faster ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using KCdod's answer, I got it to work:

```
$row = 1; // 1-based index
$col = 0;

foreach ($this->data['total_by_city'] as $city_id => $total_city){
    $city_name = '';
    foreach ($this->data['total_by_legal_entities'] as $legal_entity_id => $total_legal_entity) {
        $legal_entity_name = '';


        foreach ($this->data['restaurant_by_legal_entities'][$legal_entity_id] as $restaurant_id) {
            $orders = $this->data['order_by_restaurants'][$restaurant_id];
            $restaurant_name = '';
            if ($orders)
            {
                foreach ($orders as $order_id => $order)
                {
                        $restaurant_name = $order['restaurant_name'];
                        $legal_entity_name = $order['legal_entity'];
                        $city_name = $order['city'];
                        echo $row . ", ". $col . "<br>";
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['city']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['legal_entity']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['restaurant_name']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['payment_method']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['order_number']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['date_created']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['customer_name']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['order_type']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['amount']);
                        $row++;
                        echo $row . ", ". $col . "<br>";
                        $col = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgot to increment Column index I guess

try following

```
    $row = 1; // 1-based index
    $col = 0;

    foreach ($this->data['total_by_city'] as $city_id => $total_city){
        $city_name = '';
        foreach ($this->data['total_by_legal_entities'] as $legal_entity_id => $total_legal_entity) {
            $legal_entity_name = '';


            foreach ($this->data['restaurant_by_legal_entities'][$legal_entity_id] as $restaurant_id) {
                $orders = $this->data['order_by_restaurants'][$restaurant_id];
                $restaurant_name = '';
                if ($orders)
                {
                    foreach ($orders as $order_id => $order)
                    {
                        $restaurant_name = $order['restaurant_name'];
                        $legal_entity_name = $order['legal_entity'];
                        $city_name = $order['city'];
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['city']);
                         $col++; // Increment for each Cell
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['legal_entity']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['restaurant_name']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['payment_method']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['order_number']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['date_created']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['customer_name']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['order_type']);
                        $col++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order['amount']);

                    }
                    $col=0;
                    $row++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note- in excel each Cell should have unique RowID and ColumnID

Comment: Hello @KCdod! I did what you asked, and here are the new data about the rows and columns: http://puu.sh/dHDrB/796147a5aa.png I think we are forgetting to reset the column again.

Comment: yes after inner most insert we need to reset $col=0;

Comment: Hi KCdod. I have updated my code with the updated rows and columns. That seems more "correct", in that the rows and columns are consistent and incremented correctly. However, I still receive the same corrupted file error.

Comment: Excel cells need to have unique Row index and a column index. Since you have many for each loops check whether you update indexes properly  :)

Comment: I got it! Please check my answer =). We needed to reset the column immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I am using from_array:

```
$arrayData = array(
array(NULL, 2010, 2011, 2012),
array('Q1',   12,   15,   21),
array('Q2',   56,   73,   86),
array('Q3',   52,   61,   69),
array('Q4',   30,   32,    0),); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(
    $arrayData,  // The data to set
    NULL,        // Array values with this value will not be set
    'C3' );        // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where we want to set these values (default is A1)
```

In a project with PHP, I assigned values in a multidimensional array, and this function works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know about that fromArray() function, very helpful. Thank you!