# PhpExcel: Passing parameters then set cell value dynamically

Tags: php, phpexcel

From main.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];    
<a href="second.php?id=".$id."&name=apple">Excel</a>
```

How to get the parameters from the url, id and name
to Excel and set the cell value dynamically?

Given that there is 2 ids.

Assume that second.php has all the PhpExcel codes.

Comment: Use `$_GET` array

Comment: Please provide more detail as it is difficult to derive from your question what your actual problem is!

Comment: @M.S Supposed that id parameter has 2 values: 1 and 2, I want the two values to be printed out dynamically in excel using phpexcel. So the expected output would b A1, 1 A2, 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); //or whatever sheet you like

$index = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $index + 1, $id);
```

*(not tested)*

Please refer to [PHPExcel how to set cell value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584954/phpexcel-how-to-set-cell-value-dynamically) for a similar question.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply and thank you for your response. I tried this but it is only printing 1 id instead of 2

Comment: @AntheaMarie Hey, no problem at all. I'm sorry that I misunderstood you: Are you aiming to pass those two values inside the same request? Is `?id1=1&id2=2` and then `$id1 = $_GET['id1']; $id2 = $_GET['id2'];` an option?